# Check if input value already exist in an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my code to check if the value submitted in "username" already exist in "usernames" list. If it does, would like to have the message displayed and if it does not, add that value to the "usernames" list and submit form.

Don't understand why my code doesn't work. Please see below:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Validating Form Data</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <h3>Register your account:</h3>
    <p id="errors"></p>
    <form id="registration-form" method="POST" action="https://formdump.codeinstitute.net/">
        <div class="username">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="password">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required>
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
        
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-DrT5NfxfbHvMHux31Lkhxg42LY6of8TaYyK50jnxRnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
label {
    display: block;
}
input {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
p {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

JS

```
let usernames = ["Harry", "Daisy", "Michael", "Sarah", "Sally"];

// Write your code here
let form = document.getElementById("registration-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

let errorMsg = document.getElementById("errors");
let uName = form.elements["username"].value;

let abc = usernames.includes(uName);

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (abc) {
        errorMsg.innerHTML = `<p>Sorry, the username ${uName} is already in use. Please choose another username.</p>
  `;
    } else {
        usernames.push(uName);
        form.submit();
        console.log(usernames);
    }
}
```

I tried replacing `includes()` with `indexOf()`, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Needs to put `let uName = form.elements["username"].value;let abc = usernames.includes(uName);` inside `handleSubmit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment,you need to get the input value correctly each time it submit,so needs to put below code inside `handleSubmit`,otherwise `uName` will be null and `abc` will always be false(due to it execute before submiting)

```
let uName = form.elements["username"].value;
let abc = usernames.includes(uName);
```

```js
let usernames = ["Harry", "Daisy", "Michael", "Sarah", "Sally"];

// Write your code here
let form = document.getElementById("registration-form");
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

let errorMsg = document.getElementById("errors");

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let uName = form.elements["username"].value;
    let abc = usernames.includes(uName);
    if (abc) {
        errorMsg.innerHTML = `<p>Sorry, the username ${uName} is already in use. Please choose another username.</p>
  `;
    } else {
        usernames.push(uName);
        form.submit();
        console.log(usernames);
    }
}
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
}
input {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
p {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Validating Form Data</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <h3>Register your account:</h3>
    <p id="errors"></p>
    <form id="registration-form" method="POST" action="https://formdump.codeinstitute.net/">
        <div class="username">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="password">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required>
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
        
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-DrT5NfxfbHvMHux31Lkhxg42LY6of8TaYyK50jnxRnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Andy Yeah,I am updating it